# Redimension and paste dynamic ranges in VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, dynamic, range

i'm new to VBA and I'm having problems with arrays and ranges. I have to write a function to select portions of a range made of values with a time stamp and report them in a separate range.

The range is like this one:

```
            A           B
1   15-May-11 23:47:40  False
2   15-May-11 23:49:10  False
3   15-May-11 23:49:10  False
4   15-May-11 23:50:52  True
5   15-May-11 23:50:52  False
6   15-May-11 23:51:56  False
7   15-May-11 23:51:56  True
8   15-May-11 23:53:24  False
9   15-May-11 23:53:24  False
```

and I have prepared this function:

```
Function selectEvents(rangeTimeValue, Val As String)
    Dim outputRange() As Variant
    j = 1

    For i = 1 To rangeTimeValue.Height
    Val_recorded = rangeTimeValue(i, 2).Value
    Time_recorded = rangeTimeValue(i, 1).Value
        If Val_recorded = Val Then
            ReDim Preserve outputRange(j, 2) '(1)
            outputRange(j, 1) = Time_recorded
            outputRange(j, 2) = Val_recorded
            j = j + 1
        End If
    Next i

    selectEvents = Application.Transpose(outputRange) '(2)
End Function
```

now, there are two problems:

1. the function breaks when the array
   is re-dimensioned the second time
   (1)
2. I have an error also when
   pasting the results (2) because the
   range should be defined before I
   guess, but I don't manage to find a
   way to pass the range's dimension in
   a parametric way

I would be grateful of any help, Thanks!

Comment: What is the type of `rangeTimeValue`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1. ReDim Preserve**

Quoting from VBA help

> If you use the **Preserve** keyword, you can resize only the last array dimension

...while you are trying to `ReDim Preserve` the first dimension. Besides, `ReDim Preserve` is an expensive operation and you should avoid it unless it's absolutely necessary, which it isn't in your case. Since you can figure out the maximum number of elements your array will contain, just `ReDim` it once at the top of your code.

Also, it is good practice to specify the lower bounds of your array explicitly, rather than just let them be whatever the default is and hope for the best.

Example of how to do both these things:

```
Dim nVal As Long
nVal = WorksheetFunction.CountA(rangeTimeValue.Columns(1))
ReDim outputRange(1 To nVal, 1 To 2)
```

**2. "Pasting" the results**

I'm not sure what you mean here, because you're not pasting anything anywhere. Is this a typo where you meant pas**s**ing? Or do you mean transposing? I can't figure out what you're trying to do on that line with `.Transpose`. I don't know. I'll just take a stab in the dark:

If you want to place the contents of your `outputRange` array somewhere on your sheet, then this is how you could do it:

```
Dim rngOutput As Range
Set rngOutput = Sheet1.Range("G12") ' or wherever
rngOutput.Resize(UBound(outputRange, 1), UBound(outputRange, 2)) _
    = outputRange
```

By the way, `outputRange` is a pretty terrible name for your array. It's not a `Range`, so this name can lead to confusion, and I think it has indeed done so for you. Why not call it e.g. `varOutput` instead, since it's a `Variant` array.

Comment: Thanks, but i continue to have an error at the line 'rngOutput.Resize(UBound(outputRange, 1), UBound(outputRange, 2)) = outputRange'

Comment: "an error"... You're not giving me much to work with, are you. What error, exactly? What's the value of `nVal`? What's the content of `outputRange` just before you place it on the sheet? Do you find this answer useful at all?

Comment: sorry, I just fixed it, it was a problem with the declaration of the variables, above in the code. I think we can consider the case closed. Thanks!